# What is the difference between Memgraph Docker images?

Tags: docker, graph-databases, docker-image, memgraphdb

I can see that Memgraph has a couple of Docker images available on the Docker Hub. There is: `memgraph-platform`, `memgraph-mage` and `memgraph` image. What is the difference between those three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the image you install you get various products:

- If you run `memgraph` image you will install MemgraphDB and mgconsole (command-line interface for running queries)
- If you run `memgraph-mage` image you will install MemgraphDB, mgconsole and  [MAGE](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage) (library with advanced graph algorithms)
- If you run `memgraph-platform` image you will install MemgraphDB, MAGE, mgconsole and [Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-lab/) (visual user interface for running queries and visualizing graph data)

Keep in mind that if you installed `memgraph-platform`, mgconsole will start automatically when you run the container. If you have installed `memgraph` or `memgraph-mage`images mgconsole will not start automatically. You will need to run it using the command `docker run -it --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph --host CONTAINER_IP`. You can find more details in the [official documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/mgconsole).

So run the image depending on what products you need. If you are not sure Memgraph Platform is always a good choice because you'll get the complete solution.